# How to give messege to user or show loader on execution of function which excute on click of ribbon button on word online or word client application?

Tags: office-js

I am trying to  show a loader or message to user while executing function from ribbon button on word online and word client application.But could not find any method ,please suggest if any way present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open dialogs from the function. The dialog can be closed from the parent that opened it. See [Use the Office Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). Would this meet your needs?